# What width gate for parking 4m car at 90degrees in 10ft offset in front of home?

Tags: civil-engineering, car, home-improvement

I have 10x30 feet offset in front of my house where 30 feet is the width of my house. The road in front of house is 20 feet wide (but I can't park on road). I have a bought a 4m long car (MarutiSuzuki Brezza) with 1790mm width and 5.2m turning radius. I am planning to park it in that 10 feet offset space. Since the car is longer than the 10 feet offset space, I will have to take 90 degree turn and park it in the offset area. I am unable to decide how wide gate shall I use. My current gate is only 8 feet wide and it definitely doesn't work. Will a 12 feet gate work. Or are there any other suggestions to smartly park it inside. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_radius).

Comment: Use a Volvo 240 series - excellent turning circle...

Comment: Car width 1790mm, turning radius 5.2m.

Comment: @AJN Since my current gate is 8 ft, I have tried every possible way to make a 90 degree turn but it is not possible. It is not a near miss as well. Can you share the calculations as well.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. The answer given below appears to be in the right direction. Superimpose a 30ft x 10ft rectangle on the picture in the answer and measure the width of the gate from it. Leave some extra width for inexperienced drivers.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a bought a 4 m long car (MarutiSuzuki Brezza) with 1790 mm width and 5.2 m turning radius.

That's not enough information to provide a proper calculated solution. Given the wheelbase one could plot the path of the wheels (assuming that the 5.2 m radius refers to the distance from the centre of the turning circle to outer side of the outside front wheel (which will be the furthermost point from the centre.

Meanwhile, the body will have overhang on the front and rear which will increase the maximum swept radius while the the side of the body in line with the rear axle will determine the inner radius.

[image]

*Figure 1. The paths of various points on the car. (Image mine.)*

My advice? Find a suitable area to mark off a mock-up and use a couple of wheely bins as gateposts. Make it so that anyone can get in. You might also want to consider access for deliveries, ambulance and fire truck.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helps to go in a positive direction. My plan was also to do the same and these comments and answers build my confidence to take it.