# Will car be able to fit in from this gate from front, as well as from rear?

Tags: civil-engineering, car, highway-engineering

The gate is 8 ft (96 inches) and the road is 10 ft (120 inches). I am not a engineer nor a professional .

Help me calculate stuff, please.
[image: Image of gate and road]

Comment: Are you trying to turn the car into the box on the left?

Comment: Missing information: 1. Turning circle of the vehicle? 2. Length of wheelbase? 3. Overhang at the front. 4. Overhang at the rear. 5. Clearance space required to open passenger doors. 6. Width of car.

Comment: Related: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/what-width-gate-for-parking-4m-car-at-90degrees-in-10ft-offset-in-front-of-home/56787#56787.

Comment: Well use the handbrake: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRXW7Ne1_88

Comment: even if you could, it would be miserable, IMHO. And especially doubtful about backing it in.

Comment: where is the road?

Comment: No i have to fit it to right box, left one is road

Comment: @Transistor the road and parking is on same level

Comment: @jsotola the left one is road , right box is parking

Comment: @SolarMike i watched the youtube video. i thank you for it. But i am just an old guy and my community has mostly old people too , i don't think they will be able to do it like that.

Comment: "*...  the road and parking is on same level*", I said that you needed to supply five pieces of information. Whether or not the road and parking were on the same level was not one of them. Also, @Abel asked you in the first post whether you needed to turn left or right on the way out - or both. You didn't answer that.

Comment: @Transistor turn right . in the right is the parking

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with a ruler and compass on a scaled drawing as shown in [What width gate for parking 4m car at 90degrees in 10ft offset in front of home?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/what-width-gate-for-parking-4m-car-at-90degrees-in-10ft-offset-in-front-of-home/56787#56787), but you might be better off finding some sand or damp ground, mark out the gateway with some gardening sticks or bamboos, do the maneuver with the car and measure the results (but not forgetting the overhang at each end of the car). It looks tight.

---

[image]

*Figure 1. Image from [Dimensions.com](https://www.dimensions.com/element/passenger-vehicle-90-degree-turning-path-radius).*

According to Figure 1, you should have 3.5 m + 2.3 m = 5.8 m road width to allow comfortable turning. You have 2.9 m - only half the recommended space.

Comment: And specify the car turning circle or are you assuming a Volvo? 240 series had a fantastic turning circle :)

Comment: i am so old that i don't understand this .

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: rear wheels don't track with front wheel without rear wheel steering,  The rear wheels (& thus rear fender) will track inside the front wheel track.

Comment: @TigerGuy, the diagram isn't attempting to show the wheel tracks. It's showing comfortable turning radii. (But you know that!)